# jQuery UI datepicker display without action

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Is it possible to display jQuery UI datepicker without having to click on anything?
I want the datepicker to be visible when the window loads. Or is this not possible? If not is there another plugin for this or is it best to create a new on my own?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

one thing you could do is give focus to the input so that the datepicker shows:

```
 $('#datepicker').focus()
```

look here http://jsbin.com/agazes/edit#preview

or show it after creating it:

```
 $('#datepicker').datepicker('show')
```

http://jsbin.com/agazes/2/edit#preview

Answer (score 1):

This does not seem to be possible by passing an option. However, you can call the `show` method after creating your datepicker:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#yourElement").datepicker({
        // your options...
    }).datepicker("show");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-show

You could call the show method when you want it to open.

Answer (score 0):

In Some jQuery versions show is not available, in that case use:

```
      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        document.getElementById('datepicker').click();

     });
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
             $('#datepicker').bind('touchstart click', function(){
                    $(this).focus();
                 });
     });
```